# Storing arrays in localStorage error

Tags: javascript

I have a bug in my code that only saves the last object in an array upon reload. I have a feeling that my addAccount() function is not saving or inserting data correctly. Everything else works correctly. In my console, it shows that the data is being inserted into the array, but when I refresh I only get the last object saved.
    I'm not sure what to do.

```js
    // The list of accounts array.
    var accountsArray = [];
    function addAccount() {
     // Take fields and put user data into varables.
     var accountName = document.getElementById('accountName').value;
        var accountBalance = document.getElementById('accountBalance').value;
        var accountType = document.getElementById("accountType");
     var accountTypeSelected = accountType.options[accountType.selectedIndex].text;
     var accountCurrency = document.getElementById("accountCurrency");
     var accountCurrencySelected = accountCurrency.options[accountCurrency.selectedIndex].text;
     
     var temporaryObject = {
      'accountName': accountName,
      'accountBalance': accountBalance,
      'accountTypeSelected': accountTypeSelected,
      'accountCurrencySelected': accountCurrencySelected
     };
     
     accountsArray.push(temporaryObject);
     console.log(accountsArray);
     
     saveAccountData();
        showAccountsArray();
    }
    function saveAccountData() {
     localStorage.setItem('accountsArray', JSON.stringify(accountsArray));
    }
    function showAccountsArray() {
     //var accountsLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage['accountsArray']);
     if (localStorage.getItem("accountsArray") === null) {
      document.getElementById("getStarted").style.visibility="visible";
      document.getElementById("balanceToolbarName").style.visibility="hidden";
      document.getElementById("accountsMainList").style.visibility="hidden";
     } else {
     
      var accountsLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage['accountsArray']);
      console.log(accountsLocalStorage);
      
      var accountInfo = '';
      var i = 0;
      while (i < accountsLocalStorage.length) {
       accountInfo += '<li class="swipeout"><a href="#" class="item-link"><div class="swipeout-content item-content"><div class="item-inner"><div class="item-title">' + accountsLocalStorage[i].accountName + '</div><div class="item-after">$' + accountsLocalStorage[i].accountBalance + '</div></div></div><div class="swipeout-actions-left"><a href="#" class="action1">Clear</a></div><div class="swipeout-actions-right"><a href="#" class="action1">Delete</a></div></a></li>';
       document.getElementById("accountsList").innerHTML = accountInfo;
            i++;
      }
      
      document.getElementById("getStarted").style.visibility="hidden";
      document.getElementById("balanceToolbarName").style.visibility="visible";
      document.getElementById("accountsMainList").style.visibility="visible";
     }
     
    }
```

*

Comment: where in your code are you calling `addAccount()`? Are you calling it more than once before you call saveAccountData()? I believe saveAccountData will destroy whatever you put in there prior, so, if you're not calling `addAccount()` multiple times before you call `saveAccountData()` you will indeed wind up with just the last item you saved there.

Comment: @GeniaS. I kind-of understand what you're saying. I posted all the code on my website — this app is a web app [link to web, balance pro](http://www.jordankennedy.com/balancepro/index.html)

Comment: @GeniaS. how would that possibly happen if `accountsArray` is a global variable? `saveAccountData` stores whatever is inside the `accountsArray` variable...so, I think your theory doesn't explain why `saveAccountData` is saving the last item

Comment: @Leo, indeed... but I'm asking where in the code the OP is calling `addAcount()`.  Without that call, nothing useful happens, right? And it's not in the sample provided.

Comment: @jryankennedy it's working perfectly for me...added two items...refreshed the browser it loaded successfully from the local storage

Comment: There is a button in the html that calls the addAccount() function

Comment: @Leo - correct, now add one more item. that's when it breaks.

Comment: @GeniaS. that's a fair question...however, I was refering to `saveAccountData`...it doesn't save the last item, it saves whatever the global array holds

Comment: @jryankennedy got it...fairly simple fix...I'll post an answer instead

Comment: @Leo, you're correct... upon closer inspection, I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code, so, I'm just asking for what I can't see.  
Are you sure you're not reloading the page after this call? If you did then the global array would get reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all of your functions work correctly as tested by the link you've provided. When the page loads it successfully retrieves the data (if any) from the local storage and displays on the page. However, the global array variable `accountsArray` is populated with data retrieved from the local storage.

You need to repopulate the global array otherwise when you call `saveAccountData` it will save whatever the array holds which indeed overrides whatever you had in the local storage. To fix it, simply add add this code block...

```
$(function(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem("accountsArray");

    if(data != null)
        accountsArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("accountsArray"));
});
```